How to reference an attribute defined in a different module
OK, so I have a module called "Gridbox" which is a layout widget I wrote a very long time ago.
Within Gridbox is the file res/values/gridboxAttrs.xml which contains (abridged):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="Gridbox_Layout">
    <attr name="layout_weightx" format="float" />
    <attr name="layout_weighty" format="float" />
 </declare-styleable>
</resources>

In my application module I have res/values/styles.xml which references resources defined above:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <!-- Style for a normal button -->
  <style name="baseButton">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="layout_weightx">1</item>
    <item name="layout_weighty">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">1dip</item>
  </style>
</resources>

This built just fine under Eclipse, but Android Studio gives me
ERROR: /Users/falk/MyProject/MyApp/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/packageDebugResources/values/values.xml:372:5-384:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/layout_weightx (aka org.efalk.myapp.test:attr/layout_weightx)' not found.

I'm guessing I need to do something to get Android Studio to know that the module "MyApp" depends on module "Gridbox". My MyApp/build.gradle file does end with
dependencies {
    implementation project(':Gridbox')
}

For completeness, here is settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "MyProject"
include ':Gridbox'
include ':MyApp'

I have no idea what else I should be doing.

Well, thanks for all your advice everybody. Nobody had the answer but I got some good pointers. StackOverflow wants me to award the points to somebody, so I give them to REZON HAQUE as he had the most informative post.
I wound up doing what I should have done in the first place. I created a whole new project with a library module, and then copied file after file from the broken module into the new one until it broke.
The error turned out to be in build.grade right at the top:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

should have been
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

Again, this used to compile under an older version of Android Studio. There's no way I could have figured out the problem from the error messages from the build. Trial-and-error was really the only solution. Days of work lost on this stupid problem.

You are probably using AGP 7+ which requires "namespace" defined in build.gradle  of Gridbox. In older versions of AGP namespace would be taken from the package defined in AndroidManifest.xml of the sdk.
Solution 1
android {
    namespace 'org.efalk.gridbox' // new line
    compileSdk 31
    ..
}

Add above line in build.gradle
Solution2
Lower AGP version in main project.

Unfortunately, adding the "namespace" attribute didn't help. Good thinking, though.

Not sure about your SDK version, but probably adding a module-info.java file in MyApp help? i.e. to specify the dependency on Gridbox:
something like this:
module MyApp {
   requires Gridbox;
}

